# Purpose of mapDispatchToProps in Redux land

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there a purpose to mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addProductToCart: product => dispatch(addProductToCart(product))
  }
}
```

or is it acceptable to just do this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {dispatch};
}
```

and then just call:

`props.dispatch()` in the component

Comment: If you're as lazy as I am, you may use [`useDispatch()`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch) hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` allows you to simply specify actions your component needs to dispatch. You may take this approach because it's more declarative (letting the `mapDispatchToProps` handle all the heavy lifting so you can easily call a function from your component) or perhaps you want to share the dispatch function with an unconnected redux component.

In fact, it is perfectly acceptable not to have a `mapDispatchToProps` function at all.

Additionally based on your example. Instead of doing the following:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {dispatch};
}
```

You could simply exclude the `mapDispatchToProps` function from the `connect` method like so:

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Then do the following in your component:

```
props.dispatch({ type: 'MY_ACTION' })}
```

Comment: Additionally it separates concerns. Your component shouldn't really know anything about your actions. By passing the `dispatch` function, you're coupling your component to Redux. Mapping them to prop functions facilitates a cohesive structure which doesn't leak implementation details, like the fact that you're using Redux, into your component. `this.props.addProductToCart` could be adapted to another library in the future, if you choose to migrate from Redux. This makes refactoring much simpler.

Comment: using TypeScript, it's easier to manually include the `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {dispatch};
}` and then use `ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>`

Comment: I would argue that it's a bad practice to let easiness dictate your code structure. Prioritize for better design patterns.

Comment: Note that [we specifically now recommend using the `ConnectedProps<T>` helper](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically) to infer the types of the props that `connect` is passing to your component.

Answer (score 0):

Without `mapDispatchToProps`:-

```
this.props.dispatch(showAlert(message));
```

With `mapDispatchToProps`:-

```
this.props.onShowAlert(message);
```

THis was the main perpose of `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: I think it would be `this.props.onShowAlert` bro, right?

Comment: You might have misunderstood the question. They're asking _why_ someone would choose one approach to the other.